# An error from word-count program: expected expression

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, fstream, word-count

I ran into this error and it doesn't make any sense.

```
30:5: error: expected expression
                  [&](string & s){ M[s]++; } );
                  ^
```

Here are my codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream in_file( "sample_doc.txt" );
  ofstream out_file( "output.txt" );

  istream_iterator< string > is( in_file );
  istream_iterator< string > eof;

  map< string, int > M;
  copy( is, eof, inserter(M, begin(M)));

  for_each(istream_iterator<string>(is),
          istream_iterator<string>(),
          [&](string & s){ M[s]++; } );
  sort( M.begin(), M.end() );

  ostream_iterator<string> os( out_file, " " );
  copy( M.begin(), M.end(), os );

  return 0;
}
```

It's a word-count program. I wrote these codes try to store words from "sample_doc.txt" and figure the frequency of occurrence of each word in a "map". 
The key is the word, the value is the count of the number of times the word appears in the "sample_doc.txt".
Besides, I try to not use any low-level C++ loops.
Most importantly, when I ran this program in Eclipse, I got about 13 errors very strange, it's not like bug or something. It keep saying:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/..
    /include/c++/v1/algorithm:1751:19: 
        error: no viable overloaded '='
                *__result = *__first;
                ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~
```

OR:

```
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/..
/include/c++/v1/algorithm:3855:40: error: invalid operands to binary expression 
('std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>,
 std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>, void *> *, long> >' and 
'std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>, 
std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>, void *> *, long> >')
            difference_type __len = __last - __first;
                                    ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~
```

OR:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/..
/include/c++/v1/algorithm:3946:33: error: invalid operands to binary expression 
('std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>, 
std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>, void *> *, long> >' and 
'std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>, 
std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>, void *> *, long> >')
                        if (__i >= __j)
                            ~~~ ^  ~~~
```

Something like these and there are 13 of them. I'm so confused and I have to ask it here.
Even hints are valuable to me.
Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if the code worked as is. It makes sense to certain degree. However, C++ is not that easy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream in_file( "sample_doc.txt" );
  ofstream out_file( "output.txt" );

  istream_iterator< string > is( in_file );
  istream_iterator< string > eof;

  map< string, int > M;
  copy( is, eof, inserter(M, begin(M)));
```

You cannot into the `std::map` this way. Elements of `std::map` are instances of `std::pair<std::string, int>` but your input iterator provides only `std::string` items.

```
  for_each(istream_iterator<string>(is),
          istream_iterator<string>(),
          [&](string & s){ M[s]++; } );
```

This is actually good enough. You do not need the previous `copy`.

```
  sort( M.begin(), M.end() );
```

Sorting an `std::map` does not make any sense. It is sorted by its key. You will have to copy the map elsewhere, like into an `std::vector`.

```
  ostream_iterator<string> os( out_file, " " );
  copy( M.begin(), M.end(), os );
```

It is not possible to print out the `std::map` this way. There is no overload for printing `std::pair<>`. You basically need an ordinary loop or `for_each()` and do the printing manually.

```
  return 0;
}
```

---

Here is fixed code ([Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61c037d1351a0c57)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <sstream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream in_file( "main.cpp" );
  ofstream out_file( "output.txt" );

  istream_iterator< string > is( in_file );
  istream_iterator< string > eof;

  map< string, int > M;
  for_each(istream_iterator<string>(is),
          istream_iterator<string>(),
          [&](string const & s){ M[s]++; } );
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> > V (M.begin(), M.end());
  sort( V.begin(), V.end(),
      [&](std::pair<std::string, int> const & p1, std::pair<std::string, int> const & p2)
      {return p1.second > p2.second;});

  ostream_iterator<string> os( std::cout, " " );
  for(auto const & p : V) {
      std::ostringstream oss;
      oss << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";
      *os = std::move (oss.str());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: still get that error：31:11: error: expected expression
          [&](string const & s){ M[s]++; } );
          
      [&](std::pair<std::string, int> const & p1, std::pair<std::string, int> const & p2)

Comment: both errors point to the ' [ '. in the for_each loop, third parameter. I don't know why, it does't make any sense.

Comment: @Dorothy Do you have C++11 support enabled?

Comment: @wilx I can't put my file in with ifstream in_file( "sample_doc.txt" ); I'm sure that my file is in the directory of Eclipse and in the project. But just nothing happened after I ran. Besides, I can run your program in the link you give, but I cannot run it on eclipse with input of "main.cpp". Just nothing happened after I ran. Build is OK and I got C++ 11 support enabled. Can you help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Dorothy: I have used `main.cpp` as input just for the test. You have to replace that with your own input file. If you have issues opening the file, try using absolute path to the input file.

Comment: @wilx Thing is that I cannot even use main.cpp for testing. In eclipse it doesn't work either.